# problems with footprint in scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter

Tags: python, scipy, ndimage

I am using scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter to find out the local maxima with the code like this:

```
neighborhood = ndimage.morphology.generate_binary_structure(2,2)
fore_ground=scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter(iobrcbr,neighborhood)
```

However, when I running in python it has error:"sequence argument must have length equal to input rank". Could you please help me to fix this error? I am new in scipy.

Thanks so much.

Kind regards,

Lotus

Comment: I think you need to specify that `neighborhood` is the `footprint` argument of `maximum_filter`.  The second positional argument is `size`.  Try `maximum_filter(iobrcbr, footprint=neighborhood)`.